# QVector<QVector int> > modify "inside" vector

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following variable in QT:

```
QVector<QVector <int> > buff_d1;
```

and I need to modify the "inner" vector:

```
buff_d1.at(i).removeFirst();
buff_d1.at(i).push_back(d1.at(i).at(sample_number));
```

this is causing the errors:

```
    passing 'const QVector<int>' as 'this' argument of 'void QVector<T>::removeFirst() [with T = int]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] buff_d2.at(i).removeFirst();
    passing 'const QVector<int>' as 'this' argument of 'void QVector<T>::push_back(const T&) [with T = int]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] buff_d1.at(i).push_back(d1.at(i).at(sample_number));
```

I understand that the "inner" vector is const so I can't modify it, but what is the work around it?

Answer (score 5):

Your [at()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvector.html#at) function returns a `const` reference:

```
const T & QVector::at(int i) const
```

and you're trying to modify this with the [removeFirst()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvector.html#removeFirst) function. You should rather use the [[] operator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvector.html#operator-5b-5d) to modify it since it provides a non-const returning overload:

```
T & QVector::operator[](int i)
```

The same applies for the second error.

Comment: or  [value(int at)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvector.html#value). Method `at` is used to prevent creation of deep copy (for example when iterating over a vector).

Answer (score 1):

`at(int index)` member function returns an const reference, see the documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvector.html#at), so you need to use `operator[int index]` to return a non const reference to be able to modify it.